# Getting database disk size data mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I am quite new to mssql and I would like to know is there any query that I can used in order to collect the disk size assigned to the sql server and the percentage of disk size already used by the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.database_files
```

Or:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190674.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to collect the whole server as a whole. Because I would like to monitor how many space has been used up by the database in c drive